# Change enviroment variables in next after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

is there any way to change the environment variables after the build in next?
i need a button to change the value of an environment variable for test purposes, like if i have a variable called `NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENCY=USD` i want to be able to click a button and change for CAD (just an example)

Comment: You want to change the value of the variable by modifying the `.env` file automatically?

Comment: basically i need a global value that i can modify by just clicking a button @Samathingamajig